# Android Navigation Component: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown destination during deep linking

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I've had a look around and it seems the issue is still not resolved.

I'm using NavigationExtensions.kt with Bottom Navigation. Whenever I open the app using a deeplink to an inner fragment, it works well with a Samsung device, but on a Huawei device, the app opens up the page and when I try to navigate away, it crashes.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown destination during
>   deep link:

I'm using version 2.2.0-alpha01

Anyone with a similar issue? I've seen a couple of similar questions on the site, but it seems people have answered saying it was fixed in an earlier version of the navigation library, but for me, it is not.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118975714

Answer (score -1):

Referring to this, I found an answer:

[Navigation destination unknown to this NavController after an activity result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101617/navigation-destination-unknown-to-this-navcontroller-after-an-activity-result)

Create an action inside the fragment in the navigation graph and then use

`Navigation.findNavController().navigate(R.id.xxx)`

Hope this helps someone.